# share pointer between father and child processes

Tags: c, linux, pointers, process, fork

I've created a C program on Linux using the function Fork() inside the main process to create another child.

My objective is to create a pointer (int*) in the main process and change it inside the child process, and after the child is killed we come back to main process and display the value of the pointer (int*).

**This is how my program looks like:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (){
    int i, *x, f;
    *x = 0;
    printf("address from father: %p pid: %d\n", x, getpid());

    f = fork();

    if (f==0) {
        *x = 5;//change the value of the pointer inside the child
        printf("address from son: %p ppid: %d\n", x, getppid());
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(NULL);   
    printf("x = %d\n", *x);
    exit (0);
}
```

the link: http://openensak.com/img/code.png

**And this what the program display:**

```
address from father: 0x7fff9b698340 pid: 4372
address from son: 0x7fff9b698340 ppid: 4372
x = 0
```

the link: http://openensak.com/img/display.png

*Now the problem is that the value of the pointer is not changed even if the pointer inside and outside the child share the same memory address (0x7fff9b698340 ).*

Thanks.## Heading ##

Comment: You *do* know that two separate processes have two separate process spaces, right?

Comment: yeah, but in the memory there is one frame has the address of (0x7fff9b698340)!

Comment: Why are you using a separate process instead of a thread?

Comment: It's virtual memory.  Many processes can have the same address. Use shared memory instead if you want to do this.

Comment: because it's a homework, i have to do it as my teacher want!

Comment: hey @Duck how can i use shared memory?

Comment: If you haven't learned it in class yet then maybe the point of this exercise is to show you can't do what is being asked.  Which leads to the next lecture on how you can with shared memory.  In any event do a search here or on any search engine and you will find hundreds of articles on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fork() spawns an entirely new process---you can't modify variables from another process.

You need to use a pipe:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html

Answer (score 2):

Pipes don't directly access memory, rendering pointers useless.

*Shared memory* can be used via pointers -- but the required pointers are potentially different between the two processes, depending on where the block of shared memory gets mapped into address-space..

Like a window in a house can be at different relative heights from inside (floor level), versus outside (ground level) -- unless, as Duck says, the block is allocated pre-fork and thus already mapped in process memory.

Maybe the conclusion is, that in a modern OS with process memory-management & virtual memory, pointers are mainly meaningful and shareable within a process (for example, between threads). I would be hesitant about *depending* on pointer commonality between processes.

Comment: A shared memory segment created before the fork (as it would be in OP's case) has exactly the same address in the child after the fork.  In two unrelated processes that map a shared segment after start-up, the addresses can (and likely will be) different.

Comment: Fair enough -- but it requires the 'narrowest' case for it to work. I'd never ever design a program or write code that depended on such an assumption! :)

Comment: That's the point, it's not an assumption it's a guarantee.  Whole classes of applications (e.g. forked and pre-forked servers, for instance) that need to share or update data rely upon it.

Comment: Fair enough.. thanks for the info @Duck, I've edited my answer.